# Python pipreqs error SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Tags: python, pip

Im trying to run pipreqs --encoding=utf8

Getting the following error, any idea how I resolve? this module backtester is not my own code.

```
(cqf) C:\Users\User>pipreqs --encoding=utf8
ERROR: Failed on file: C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\cqf\Lib\site-packages\backtester\backtest\backtest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\cqf\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\cqf\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\cqf\Scripts\pipreqs.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\cqf\lib\site-packages\pipreqs\pipreqs.py", line 528, in main
    init(args)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\cqf\lib\site-packages\pipreqs\pipreqs.py", line 455, in init
    candidates = get_all_imports(input_path,
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\cqf\lib\site-packages\pipreqs\pipreqs.py", line 131, in get_all_imports
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\cqf\lib\site-packages\pipreqs\pipreqs.py", line 117, in get_all_imports
    tree = ast.parse(contents)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\cqf\lib\ast.py", line 50, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, flags,
  File "<unknown>", line 178
    "Null Hypothesis: time series is
                                    ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

I tried removing backtester module and rerunning, i get this error :

```
ERROR: Failed on file: C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\cqf\Lib\site-packages\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd_attach_to_process\_check.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\cqf\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\cqf\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\cqf\Scripts\pipreqs.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\cqf\lib\site-packages\pipreqs\pipreqs.py", line 528, in main
    init(args)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\cqf\lib\site-packages\pipreqs\pipreqs.py", line 455, in init
    candidates = get_all_imports(input_path,
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\cqf\lib\site-packages\pipreqs\pipreqs.py", line 131, in get_all_imports
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\cqf\lib\site-packages\pipreqs\pipreqs.py", line 117, in get_all_imports
    tree = ast.parse(contents)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\cqf\lib\ast.py", line 50, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, flags,
  File "<unknown>", line 2
    print add_code_to_python_process.run_python_code(3736, "print(20)", connect_debugger_tracing=False)
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

expect no error and a list of requirements output.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
In order to get help, you will need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @9769953 I upvoted before I read the error and cannot revoke it... it's actually not pipreqs that is py2 but code that pipreqs is analysing (debugpy, or rather they include code from pydevd in debugpy's installation for some reason - pipreqs is analysing all .py files and therefore it fails on legacy code, even if that code is not used anywhere). Pipreqs lists the offending file at the start of the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You're fighting symptoms, not the origin of the problem.

***pipreqs is supposed to be run for your own code, not libraries*** - libraries already list their own dependencies in their setup configuration and pip can read them.

You're running it directly in your home location, so it will run through all user files and fail on all legacy/broken code *anywhere* in there.

In this case, that's a broken file in `backtester` and python2-only code in `debugpy`, but there could be way more! And not only in installed packages where you could just uninstall it - it could be your own abandoned projects that have broken syntax, it could be anything. You'd have to just fix it file-by-file! That's why I'm saying you're fighting symptoms.

Run it properly: in your own project. It will list the libs that are used in that specific project. That's all that's needed.